# HISTSIZE not being set in bash

Tags: bash, history

I am trying to increase the size of my history in bash.  I have the following in my ~/.bash_profile

`# Control the command history

export HISTFILESIZE=10000

export HISTSIZE=10000

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups`

But, when I `echo $HISTSIZE` I always get `50`.  Am I missing something?  Is there some command that my sys admin put in a higher config file that could prevent HISTSIZE from being changed?

Comment: What happens when you `echo $HISTSIZE` immediately after you `export` it? Do you still get 50 in that instance?

Comment: @Dunnie Good question.                                                     ~$ echo $HISTSIZE
50
~$ export HISTSIZE=100
~$ echo $HISTSIZE
100
~$ 
So I can set the HISTSIZE on the command line, but not in my .bash_profile.

Comment: And do you get the same output if you place the `echo` in your `.bash_profile`? I'm basically trying to determine if your `.bash_profile` just isn't setting it at all, or if it's getting overwritten later on down the line.

Comment: @Dunnie Yeah, you were right.  One of those files sources something that changes HISTSIZE.  I have changed the order of the sourcing of files and now it works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many distributions seem to have `.bash_profile` check `.bashrc` somewhere inside of it. Could your `.bashrc` be sourced sometime later and set a `HISTSIZE` of 50?

Comment: I have checked .bashrc and (on this system) .bashrc.local; both are called after .bash_profile, neither contain anything about HISTSIZE.

Comment: Does your `.bash_profile` (or any descendants) source any other files? `/etc/profile` might also be a culprit.

Answer (score 5):

What is your OS and BASH version? try

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

I use `4.2.20(2)-release`via **Mac OS X Lion** / Homebrew... Here is my config

```
export HISTIGNORE="ls:ll:cd:pwd"
export HISTFILESIZE=3000
export HISTSIZE=3000
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[$(tput setaf 6)%F %T$(tput sgr0)]: " # colorful date
```

Try to update you bash. Also, maybe `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`or `/etc/profile` is overriding your local settings...

Answer (score 1):

Your `~/.bash_profile` may not be executing, or it there is a script later that is overriding the value. You can add some `echo bash_profile` statements to check.

Usually, these bash variables are defined in `.bashrc`, so you can try moving it there.

Also, don't use `export` with the `HIST*` variables. They are not environment variables, they are bash variables. Exporting them is useless. That's why putting them in `/etc/environment` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variables in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Putting `HISTSIZE=5000` or `HISTFILESIZE=5000` in `/etc/environment` does nothing for me. I'm in Arch Linux.

Comment: Oh, wait, putting the variables in ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc works.

Comment: It works, but it seems to require me to __login__ again? Because I have a proof that nothing has changed, because `cat ~/.bash_history | wc -l` gives a clear 2000, which is the default - and I have set about twice as much. From `bash` manual it states: *"The shell sets the default value to the value of HISTSIZE after reading any startup files."* Maybe, but it will NOT expand a `.bash_history` file that already exists. It stays at the default of 2000 lines. So before trusting `bash`, you should execute the above line to know it isn't trying to fool you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a few comments saying something was overriding my environment variable, I nullified this claim by trying set commands from the command line.
I tried set HISTSIZE 9999 & set HISTSIZE=9999, and HISTSIZE remained echoing at 2000.

Then I tried export HISTSIZE=9999 and it stayed at 9999!

I gotta get my bash syntax down right :/

The takeaway is to call:
export HISTSIZE=9999